# Why can't I write this matrix?

Tags: errors, compilation-error

I'm trying to write this 3x12 matrix, but when compiling I get the following: "Additional alignment tab has been changed to \cr"
I don't know what's going on, I'll leave here what I have in the preamble to see what could be causing the conflict

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\parindent=0mm
\usepackage{makeidx} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,amsfonts,latexsym,cancel,tikz,colortbl}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e,bm}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\author{}
\title{CÓDIGOS ALGEBRAICO-GEOMÉTRICOS Y ALGUNAS APLICACIONES}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hangafter=1\hangindent=3.3em}p{#1}}
```

The code I am using to write the matrix is

```
 \begin{equation*}
  \begin{pmatrix}
  0&0&1&1&2&2&3&4&4&5&6&0\\
  1&6&3&4&3&4&0&3&4&0&0&1\\
  1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&0
  \end{pmatrix}
  \end{equation*}
```

Comment: The `amsmath` package defines a counter named `MaxMatrixCols` and sets its default value to 10. It's relevant for the `matrix`, `pmatrix`, `bmatrix`, and `vmatrix` environments. To increase the value to, say, 12, write `\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{12}`.

Comment: Off-topic: Don't use the ancient and fairly obsolete `txfonts` package; instead, do load the `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` packages. No need to load the `amsfonts` package explicitly, as it's loaded automatically by the `amssymb` package. Since you load `amssymb`, there can be no good reason for loading the `latexsym` package. Don't load both `enumerate` and `enumitem`; hint: load just the latter package. And, unless your computing setup is *ancient* (say, more than 10 years old...), do get rid of `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}`.